# Respond with User timezone/locale from a webhook request

Tags: dialogflow-es, api-ai, fulfillment

When I receive a user request I would like to respond with a date with the user timezone. Actually, I can only respond with server TZ

Comment: Provide the code where you're responding with the date, so we can help you.

Comment: The key to this question is that it’s about responding to a dialogflow webhook request.  So the question is really “how do i get the user’s time zone out of a dialogflow webhook request?”

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, DialogFlow doesn’t make it easy by simply telling g you what timezone the user is coming from.  The best you can do is ask the user for their timezone and then save that to do date/time adjustments in future responses.

This can be optimized a bit for users accessing your agent through Google Assistant by using the new permissions API.  See https://chatbotsmagazine.com/personalize-google-assistant-skill-with-user-data-328f5e0860a0

Comment: Is this still true? This can be very important for example for dosages

Answer (score 0):

If your user responds to your agent with the parameter of @sys.date-time type, you will receive in your fulfillment the value in ISO-8601 format like "2019-12-17T22:00:00+02:00". The last 6 characters represent a timezone offset. You can use it and calculate the target local time of your users.